# Bash shell, using ps without displaying process path names

Tags: bash, ps

In a bash shell using ps, is it possible to return just process names + PIDs without their paths?
For example, using ps -A I get something like this:

```
Octo:~ decavolt$ ps -A
PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1 ??        12:29.17 /sbin/launchd
10 ??         0:01.37 /usr/libexec/kextd
11 ??         7:03.37 /usr/sbin/DirectoryService
12 ??        18:16.71 /usr/sbin/notifyd
...
```

What I'd like to see is more like:

```
PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1 ??        12:29.17 launchd
10 ??         0:01.37 kextd
11 ??         7:03.37 DirectoryService
12 ??        18:16.71 notifyd
...
```

EDIT: Sorry, I should have clarified that this is on OSX 10.5 and 10.6

Comment: On my system, using version 3.2.7, the output from -A is identical to the output you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry Anders, I should have mentioned that this is on OSX 10.5 and 10.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ss64.com/osx/ps.html

According to this page, the -c option should be what you're looking for. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, `ps -A` does what you want, however, try `ps -A c` to see if it works for you (if you're using GNU `ps`).

Comment: Yupp, produces the same result on an old Solaris 9 system with default installation also.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ps -o pid,tty,time,comm`.